# calendar value coming even if it is empty on change using JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've a calendar tag on my xhtml, initially it has some value, and when I select the information using mouse and delete it, the change event still passes the old bean object data. How can I get it as null or empty

Here is my code

```
<p:calendar id="effDate" yearRange="c:c+1"
        pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" styleClass="effDate"           
        style="box-shadow : inset 0 -1px 2px #8f8f8f;position:relative; left:20px;" immediate="true"
        value="#{myBean.calDate}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />

         <p:ajax  event="change"  listener="#{myBean.onDateModified}" ></p:ajax>

    </p:calendar>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try using a valueChangeListener?

Comment: Add valueChangeListner and get value from event

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: And **always, always, always** post version info